# laravel in subdomain, how to set up htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I want setup laravel on the hosting.

My hosting has structure:

```
   /
   |- domain.net
   |- domain.com
         |- web
         |- sub
             |- supersite
             |- calendar
                  |- vendor
                  |- bootstrap
                  |- app
                     ... (all laravel files)
```

Main site `domain.com` on my hosting is in folder `web`. All subdomains are in folder `sub`. For example my laravel site `calendar` is accesible by `calendar.domain.com`

I found this .htaccess on net.

```
DirectorySlash On
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I added into file `app/routes.php` this code

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

I put `.htaccess` into folder `calendar`. The site `calendar.domain.com` works fine, but site `calendar.domain.com/users` returned server error 500.

Do you know where is problem? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DocumentRoot is `calender` and you cannot change it to `calender/public` you can use this in your .htaccess in calendar folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```